# Отрисовка компонента Swing java

Tags: java, swing

Каким методом или каким образом можно вызвать отрисовку компонента (например, скрола или текстового поля)? У меня рисуется картинка,как фоновое изображение и она перекрывает компонент. Вот и вопрос - как после прорисовки картинки по верху отрисовать компоненту? (перепробовал уже и `revalidate`, `paint` и `repaint`)

**UPD:** вот код класса панели

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel
        implements Runnable, KeyListener,MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

    // dimensions
    public static final int WIDTH = 1200;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int SCALE = 1;

    // game thread
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

    public static int mouseX;
    public static int mouseY;

    // image
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    //level start
    public static long levelStartTimer=0;
    public static long levelStartTimerDiff=0;
    public static int levelNumber=1;
    public static boolean levelStart=true;
    public static int levelDelay = 2000;

    // game state manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;

    public GamePanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            //addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void init() {

        image = new BufferedImage(
                WIDTH, HEIGHT,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
        );
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        running = true;

        gsm = new GameStateManager();

    }

    public void run() {

        init();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        // game loop
        while(running) {

            start = System.nanoTime();

            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            if(wait < 0) wait = 5;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private void update() {
        gsm.update();
    }
    private void draw() {
        gsm.draw(g);
    }
    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0,
                WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE,
                null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
        return;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        gsm.keyPressed(key.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        gsm.click();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=e.getX();
        mouseY=e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX=e.getX();
        mouseY=e.getY();
    }
}
```

В методе draw происходит отрисовка различных менюшек и самой игры далее. Как например в этот класс впилить JTextArea так,чтобы это адекватно отрисовывалось поверх и так же адекватно работало?

Answer (score 1):

нашлось решение:
просто для теста я добавил кнопку`add(new JButton("123123123123"));`
и в конце своего метода `draw()` прописал `super.paintComponents(g);`
итого: swing элемент отрисовывается поверх моих картинок и т.д. [image: пример работы]

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема. Нужно просто написать `super.paintComponent(g);` и компоненты отрисуются автоматически.

```
class panel extends JPanel{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Здесь важно не добавить букву "s" в конец функции. То есть **НЕ** `paintComponents`, а **`paintComponent`**

Comment: мне нужно в методе draw(),который отросовывает игровую сцену при каждой отрисовке тоже вызывать отрисовку компонента

Comment: хм...помог именно метод paintComponents,доавленный в конце метода draw()